# Some Rich Text Formatting (HTML) Not Displaying in Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: python, html, ms-access, ms-office

I'm using a python script to parse a mass of text and import it into a Microsoft Access 2010 database. I'm inserting certain portions of the original text into a Rich Text section of a table.  Adding `<Br>` statements creates the intended effect of starting a new line. This are implemented in python as follows:

```
if line not in ['\n', '\r\n']:
                section += line + '<Br>'
```

However, when attempting to bold sections of text, none of the appropriate tags seem to work. I've tried:

```
sectionOrig.lower().replace(statin, '<b>' + statin + '</b>'),
sectionOrig.lower().replace(statin, '<strong>' + statin + '</strong>'), and
sectionOrig.lower().replace(word, '<span style="font-weight:bold">' + word + '</span>').
```

I've also tried adding `<html>` and `</html>` before and after each set of styling tags. The tags seem to be processed by Access because they don't show up at all within the section, but the text isn't bold. From what I've found online these are the right tags to use for bolding text, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, just saw I forgot to indent.

Comment: Are you assigning the results of the `.replace` to some variable? Strings are immutable in Python, so `thing.replace(...)` will return a new string with the replacements performed, but it will not alter the value of `thing` itself unless you do `thing = thing.replace(...)`.

Comment: Nope, didn't acknowledge that.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in Python, so the `.replace` method does not perform the replacement *in situ*, it simply returns a new string with the replacement(s) applied. So, for example, this code does not change the value of the string named `thing`:

```python
>>> thing = 'foo bar baz'
>>> thing
'foo bar baz'
>>> thing.replace('bar', 'bazinga')
'foo bazinga baz'
>>> thing
'foo bar baz'
```

but this does:

```python
>>> thing = thing.replace('bar', 'bazinga')
>>> thing
'foo bazinga baz'
```